# How is "sqlite_see_if_its_a_number" related to "mysql_bind_type_guessing"?

Tags: mysql, perl, sqlite, binding

When I try this example - as explained in the [DBD::SQLite](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD%3a%3aSQLite) [documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD%3a%3aSQLite#Functions-And-Bind-Parameters) - with `sqlite_see_if_its_a_number` disabled I don't get any result. With `sqlite_see_if_its_a_number` enabled I get the expected result:

```
$dbh->{sqlite_see_if_its_a_number} = 1;
my $sth = $dbh->prepare(q{
    SELECT bar FROM foo GROUP BY bar HAVING count(*) > ?;
});
$sth->execute(5);
```

When I try this SELECT query on a MySQL database table with the same data it works as expected regardless of the setting of [mysql_bind_type_guessing](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD%3a%3amysql#DATABASE-HANDLES).

What are the differences between these two attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MySQL automatically converts numbers to strings as necessary, and vice versa.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/type-conversion.html) This query:

```
SELECT bar FROM foo GROUP BY bar HAVING count(*) > '5'
```

is automatically converted to:

```
SELECT bar FROM foo GROUP BY bar HAVING count(*) > 5
```

The former is what `DBI` sends to the database when you use a placeholder. Since MySQL takes care of the conversion automatically, the only reason to set `mysql_bind_type_guessing` is for performance: why do unnecessary type conversions<sup>*</sup> when you don't have to?

In SQLite, on the other hand, [an INTEGER or REAL value is less than any TEXT or BLOB value.](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) Therefore, `count(*)` (INTEGER) is always less than `'5'` (TEXT). Without setting `sqlite_see_if_its_a_number`, bind values will always be enclosed by quotes, so this comparison will always fail.

---

* In recent versions of MySQL (greater than 5.1.42, 5.6.0, or 6.0.14), the performance gain may be negligible: when making a comparison with a constant (e.g. `count(*) > '5'`), the conversion is done once and the result is cached. In earlier versions, the conversion was done for each row, which caused [noticeable performance issues](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=34384) with very large quoted numbers like `'999999999999'`.

Comment: @ThisSuitlsBlackNot With this query example: is there only needed one conversion or does every grouped "bar" need a conversion (if `mysql_bind_type_guessing` is not enabled)?

Comment: @sid_com I don't see your example query.

Comment: @ThisSuitlsBlackNot MySQL: Does a query like `SELECT * FROM table WHERE number > 3` need only one conversion or a conversion for each table row (if mysql_bind_type_guessing is not enabled)?

Comment: @sid_com According to [this MySQL bug report](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=34384): "When values of different types are compared they're converted to a type that allows correct comparison. This conversion is done for each comparison and takes some time. *When a constant is being compared it's possible to cache the value after conversion to speedup comparison.*" The caching mentioned in the last sentence was fixed in MySQL 5.1.42, 5.6.0, and 6.0.14.

Comment: @sid_com So in a recent version of MySQL, the comparison `number > '3'` should do the conversion once and cache the results. `number_field > string_field` would still have to do the conversion for each row. Also note that the performance issues mentioned in that bug report are only for very large quoted numbers like `'999999999999'`.

Comment: @ThisSuitlsBlackNot I posted a bad example. I meant: `$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE number > ?"); $sth->execute(3);`. Does this count as a constant?

Comment: @sid_com DBI sends `SELECT * FROM table WHERE number > '3'` to MySQL if `mysql_bind_type_guessing` is off (you can verify by turning on the general query log). `'3'` is a literal and therefore also a constant.